# I am checking to see if any values in column C match with values from column B

Tags: excel, vba, match, vlookup

I need preferably a formula or macro in excel 2013 to do the following:

1. Check if any given values in column C match with values from column B.
2. If they do I want to take the corresponding value from the same row in column A  as the matched items in column B.
3. I then want to take those values from column A and put them in the same rows in column D.

Specifically, I am checking to see if any ID's in column C match with ID's from column B. If they do I want to take the corresponding city ID from column A in the same row as the matched items in column B.
I then want to take those values from column A and put them in the same rows in column D.

I used this formula `=VLOOKUP(C6; A2:B14; 1; FALSE)` but it returns `#N/A`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` will always use the first column as `lookup_array`.  But in your case, you are using the second column for lookup_array, and wanting to return the value in the first column.  So `VLOOKUP` is not appropriate.

Depending on your version of Excel, you could use `INDEX(MATCH` or `XLOOKUP`:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(C2,$B$2:$B$14,0))
=XLOOKUP(C2,$B$2:$B$14,$A$2:$A$14)
```

[image]

Comment: Big thanks for your answer. The INDEX and MATCH formula did the job.